# independent normal distribution sum

Tags: probability

During my lecture it was mentioned that, given two independent random variable $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and
$Y\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then their sum is also normal distributed and
$\frac{X+Y-2\mu}{\sqrt{2}} \sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$

So far I was able to prove that X+Y is $\sim\mathcal N(2\mu,2\sigma^2)$ (by using generating functions)
But now I am struggling to proof that $\frac{X+Y-2\mu}{\sqrt{2}}$ is distributed the way it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, it may be useful to know that for any absolutely continuous random variable $Z$ with mean $\mu$, $\mathbb{E}\left[Z-d\right] = \mu - d$, which you can show from $\int (z-d)f(z)\operatorname{ d }z$. Once the mean is zero, the variance is $\mathbb{E}\left[ (Z-\mu)^2 \right]$, and you can show that $\mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\frac{(Z-\mu)}{c}\right)^2 \right] = \frac{\sigma^2_{Z-\mu}}{c^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}$ and $f_{Y}(y)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}$. Now, since they are independent their joint distribution factorizes as
$$F_{X,Y}(x,x)=F_{X}(x)F_{Y}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{X}(t)dt\int_{-\infty}^yf_Y(s)ds=\int\int_A\frac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}-\frac{(s-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^2}}dtds$$
where $A=\{t,s\mid -\infty<t<x, -\infty<s<y\}$. Now if you do those squares in the exponet you will find out $(t+s-2\mu)^2$ which is exactly the the distribution of a normal $\mathcal{N}(2\mu, 2\sigma^{2})$

Answer (score 2):

Moment generating function of a random variable $Y$ is $\mathbb{E}(e^{tY})$. If $Y \sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $E(e^{tY}) = e^{\mu t +\frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2}}$.

Now if $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\mathbb{E}(e^{t.\frac{X+Y-2\mu}{\sqrt{2}}}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{t.\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}})\  e^{-\sqrt{2}\mu t} $.

Now since you've proven $X +Y \sim \mathcal{N}(2\mu,2\sigma^2)$, $\mathbb{E}(e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}. X+Y}) =  e^{\sqrt{2}\mu t + \frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2}} $.

So, $\mathbb{E}(e^{t.\frac{X+Y-2\mu}{\sqrt{2}}}) = e^{\frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}}$  -- which is the moment generating function of $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$